# how to replace pk with slug in detailview

Tags: django, django-views

how to make slug place pk?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Category,Subcategory, Product, Characteristic

class CategoryView(ListView):
    """list of categories"""
    model = Category


class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    """Full description of categories"""
    model = Category
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'name category', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='pic')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_category


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='category', related_name='sub')
    name_subcategory = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'name subcategory', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='pic')
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_subcategory
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.CategoryView.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
    ]
```

in the link template I form like this

```
{% for category in category_list %}
<a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=category.pk %}">{{category.name_category}}</a>
<img src="{{category.image.url}}" width="100px" height="100px">
   {% for img in category.sub.all %}
      {{ img.name_subcategory }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now my links are formed like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/`
how to make the place `pk` in the link substituted `slug` from the Subcategory model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model, you need a `SlugField`. It might be easy to make use of an [**`AutoSlugField`** [readthedocs]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField) the [**`django-autoslug`** package [readthedocs]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='name category',
        max_length=100,
        null=True
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        upload_to='media/',
        verbose_name='pic'
    )
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name_category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_category
```

In the url patterns you make use of a parameter named `slug`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CategoryView.as_view()),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
]
```

In the templates you then use the `slug` field instead of the primary key:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'category_detail' slug=category.slug %}">{{category.name_category}}</a>
    <img src="{{category.image.url}}" width="100px" height="100px">
    {% for img in category.sub.all %}
        {{ img.name_subcategory }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I was so close ... I tried to pull the slug from another model .. I need to practice more. Thank !